# Jquery и многомерный массив

Tags: jquery, массивы, php

Есть массив вида:

```
var data[947] = {"id":947,"name":"название родителя","child":{"948":{"id":"948","name":"назван1","child":[]},"949":{"id":"949","name":"назван2","child":[]},"950":{"id":"950","name":"назван3","child":[]}}};
```

Как получить с помощью jquery значение к примеру названия родителя?

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#test").html(data[947]['name']);
}); 
</scrit>
```

С помощью выше указанной конструкции не выходит((..

Comment: "назван2" - крутое значение) всегда так делаю));
А вообще скажите зачем вам это нужно? И как вы перебираете потомков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обращаетесь к элементу вы правильно. Проблема в том, что вы не создали объект, как полагается.

```
/* Сначала создайте родительский объект */
var data = {};

/* Потом записывайте в него значения */
data[947] = {
    "id": 947,
    "name": "название родителя",
    "child": {
        "948": {
            "id": "948",
            "name": "назван1",
            "child": []
        },
        "949": {
            "id": "949",
            "name": "назван2",
            "child": []
        },
        "950": {
            "id": "950",
            "name": "назван3",
            "child": []
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: все получилось))) спасибо, упустила было этот момент)))

Answer (score 0):

Разделите объявление и присваивание:

```
var data = {}

data[947] = {"id":947,"name":"название родителя","child":{"948":{"id":"948","name":"назван1","child":[]},"949":{"id":"949","name":"назван2","child":[]},"950":{"id":"950","name":"назван3","child":[]}}};
```

Полный пример [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8XmF/2/)